# PCB Design Finding Part Equivalents

Tags: capacitor, pcb-design, components

I'm currently designing a PCB in Eagle to build my own Nixie Clock. I know kits exist but I'm trying to do this from the ground up to get the experience. Nixie Tubes require 180V and I'm trying to mimic and existing  [SMPS Circuit](http://desmith.net/NMdS/Electronics/NixiePSU.html) (the bottom of the page has a parts list) but this was designed years ago and a lot of the parts it used are no longer available.

For Example C1: TPSD107M035 it is 100uF with a voltage rating of 35V with a comment saying to use the lowest ESR available. I'm trying to use SMD packages and I'm having trouble finding the part in Eagle. Only a handful of parts have 100uF and 35V voltage rating but they don't list the package type so I don't know what to set it as. [This capacitor](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Nichicon/UCZ1V101MCL1GS/?qs=kgXyKxmsiW0b0xIZi0HDUw%3D%3D) seems like it would work as a replacement but I cannot find its package information and I don't know if just matching 100uF and the voltage rating is all I need to do.

Would a higher voltage rating work as well? I know there is also polarized vs non-polarized capacitors exist but does that make a difference in most application?

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Yes higher voltage rating works as well. It's the highest voltage allowed to apply.  In your application (C1)  you can use a non-polarized or polarized

Comment: So then any 100uf capacitor with a voltage rating of 35 or above would work? I know there was a comment about lowest ESR but I'm not sure how important that is or what value would be considered a low ESR?

Comment: ESR is the "Qualitiy" of the Capacitor. It tells you how high the internal resistance is. The lower, the more current it can provide.  I don't think it will make a big difference in your application. More intressting for you is the ripple current. This should be higher than the current you expect to flow (2A i quess). This value is quite bad in your CAP (of course the ripple current and the ESR are physically connected)

Comment: If you select only the cap with ripple current of more than 2 A you see that they all have a ESR of 20-30m Ohm

Answer (score 5):

> I'm having trouble finding the part in Eagle

You don't find parts in Eagle, you make them.  By the time you carefully vet a part made by someone else, you could have made it yourself.  Then it will adhere to your conventions for BOM attributes, documentation layer, assembly drawing, etc.

> Would a higher voltage rating work as well?

This is a *very basic* electronics question, separate from your Eagle question.  However, yes, capacitors must be rated at least for the specified voltage, but can exceed it.

Comment: +1 for recommending making your own libraries. There are many advantages of doing it yourself.

Answer (score 4):

The part you have identified as a potential replacement has all the information in the [datasheet](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/293/e-ucz-884053.pdf).

To get the dimensions:

Get the configuration for φd
[image: CL configuration]

Now get a package (Second one down in datasheet as the one above has identical dimensioning for footprint).

[image: Package]

Now find the size to use which is 8 x 10 for this case:

[image: size table]

Now get the dimension mapping:
[image: Dimensions]

The A, B and so forth map to the package dimensions.

The original part has clearly been discontinued. It is an AVX [TPS Series](http://www.avx.com/products/tantalum/smd-tantalum-mno2/tps-series/) part in a size D case, but no longer shows up in the datasheet in the 35V section.

Note that I would not use a 35V tantalum part where the voltage can go up to 30V. Manufacturers [suggest](https://ec.kemet.com/q-and-a/how-much-do-you-derate-tantalum-caps) [derating](http://www.vishay.com/docs/40110/faq.pdf) by 50% to 60% under normal operating conditions.

The [ESR](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3539/how-to-find-the-esr-of-a-capacitor) of a capacitor in this particular position determines the ripple current it can handle. Note that the ripple current a tantalum can deal with is frequency dependent (it increases with frequency), although a tantalum device has an [unusual](http://www.avx.com/docs/techinfo/Tantalum-NiobiumCapacitors/TANTALUM_MODEL.pdf) capacitance curve.

If you can live with the predicted failure rate, then you could, alternatively, use 2 TPSE476M035#0200 in parallel. That decodes to TPS series, Size E case, capacitance = 476 (47μF), 10% tolerance (M), 35V rated voltage, 200mΩ ESR. The allowable 100kHz ripple current is just over 900mA per device.

That would yield a 94μF. 100mΩ ESR device. If you need a lower ESR, use 3 x 33μF parts in parallel (select the lowest ESR in the tables in the datasheet).

I would more likely use a 50V rated part, using parallel parts to get the required capacitance.

Low ESR is somewhat subjective, but 200mΩ is relatively low for a tantalum device. Ceramics can be as low as a few mΩ.

A higher rated voltage is fine, and this part does not seem particularly critical for capacitance value (it is a bulk input filter).

On polarised vs. non-polarised - it depends on the application; here either type could be used provided you keep the polarity correct for a polarised part.

http://www.avx.com/docs/techinfo/Tantalum-NiobiumCapacitors/TANTALUM_MODEL.pdf

Comment: I tried looking in the data sheet a few times but I didn't see what I was expecting to find for packaging info. In Eagle I'll have ex. C01005  package but I don't see anything in the data sheet that shows a number like that. I see where they break down the manufacture number and show GS as the packaging code but do I then need to take GS and compare it with a table the manufacture has elsewhere?

Comment: Don't only trust Eagle parts. The Eagle libraries are not exhaustive, and most likely will not have the part you want. You'd be better off creating your own Eagle library.